# String interpolation without #{}

Tags: ruby

Please observe the following:

```
"abcd#fg"  # => "abcd#fg"
"abcd#$fg" # => "abcd"    characters #$ and after them are skipped
"abcd#@fg" # => "abcd"    characters #@ and after them are skipped
```

It could be string interpolation just with `#` instead of `#{}`.

```
$fg = 8
"abcd#$fg" # => "abcd8" 
@fg = 6
"abcd#@fg" # => "abcd6"
```

It works like interpolation. Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: @toro2k, Thanks. I didn't notice that question.

Comment: Of course it is a feature. It is really a bad habit of beginners to so easily attribute to someone else's bug something they don't understand. I really wonder why beginners tend to think that they are correct and the software is wrong. Experienced programmers are more modest.

Comment: @sawa I don't think this is such an unreasonable question.

Comment: @WayneConrad If it asked why such thing happens, then it is not unreasonable to ask. What is unreasonable is to suspect a bug so easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually interpolate global, instance, and class variables omitting the braces:

```
$world = 'world'
puts "hello, #$world"
# hello, world
```

In your example both `$fg` and `@fg` are uninitialized and thus evaluated to `nil`, that's why they are intorpolated as empty strings. When you write `"abcd#fg"` nothing is interpolated because the `#` is not followed by one of `{`, `@`, `$`.

You can find the feature documented in the [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/string_spec.rb#L28-L38) (thanks to @DavidMiani).

If you ask me, don't rely on this behaviour and always interpolate variables using braces, both for readability and to avoid problems such:

```
@variable = 'foo'
puts "#@variable_bar"
```

This will output an empty string instead of the, probably, expected string `"foo_bar`", because it is trying to interpolate the undefined instance variable `@variable_bar`.

Comment: It is present in the [ruby spec string file](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/string_spec.rb) though, so any ruby that passes that spec will work with that syntax.

Comment: The links to RubySpec are dead. I only found that RubySpecs is closed. https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/